# Wirecloud geojson in a map

Tags: geojson, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

Hello i'm trylling to show an entity with geojson data in a map inside of Wirecloud. The data comes from my own instance of Orion. Here you have some screenshots where you can see the data from Orion and the configuration.

[General configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J50n9.png)

[Entity to POI configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3nxT.png)

[Dashboard, Json editor is just to show the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3OWH.png)

If i change the lat and long and i put it in a normal attribute with name, it works but in the geojson array it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of working, I saw that the version in the [repo](https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/ngsi-entity2poi-operator) of the component "NGSI Entity 2 PoI operator" is hightest than the one that it's in the Wirecloud's marketplace, in the last commits i saw that geojson support was added so i tried it but it didn't work so I forked the repo and i fixed it.

Here it is my fixed version.
https://github.com/xXcoronaXx/ngsi-entity2poi-operator

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are swapped in the coordinates array. Please take into account that the order of coordinates in GeoJSON is [long, lat]

thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but, if i change the order in the json editor and i push in the send button is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version of the `map-viewer` widget you were using. Take into account that we have recently released version 2.6.0, and this is the first version of the `map-viewer` widget supporting geojson. You can download it from [github](https://github.com/Wirecloud/map-viewer-widget/releases).

Once you upgrade this widget, you can change the `Coordinates attribute` setting of the `ngsientity2poi` operator to `location` as this is the attribute containing the geojson geometry to be used to represent the PoI.